# Subtracting path from document root in PHP

Tags: php

My current document root is this (via $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']):

```
/var/www/html/clients/app/folder
```

I need to generate one folder up:

```
/var/www/html/clients/app
```

How would I go about doing this?

I had asked this in the past:
[Dynamically finding paths, is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225254/dynamically-finding-paths-is-there-a-better-way)

However, I have this scenario which doesn't work:

- Executed script is located here: root/f1/f2/f3/f4/f5/file.php.
- This script includes another script located here: root/f6/file2.php

In file2.php, I needed the following code for this to work:

```
$base_path = dirname(realpath("../../../../do_not_remove.txt"));
```

When in theory, based on its location, it should have been this:

```
$base_path = dirname(realpath("../do_not_remove.txt"));
```

In practice, there would be a global available where this data could be passed. However, in this inherited project, there isn't thus I'm reusing this where I need it.

**Update #1**

Based on the answers, this seems to work great: `realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you could have - `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/../"` - even though it doesn't look too pretty

OR a slightly more propper way might be - `dirname( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] )` - think this should work

Comment: ha, I got no votes left, otherwise I'd vote for you too in the spirit of the right answer

Comment: @Ray See my update, thoughts on what seems to work? And, should I flip to see who gets the answer? :)

Comment: Hmmm, getting a little confused right now, but essentially you should get realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../"); returning an identical path to dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../");

Comment: @Ray why do I need to "substract" an extra path when using realpath?

Comment: From the php manual: realpath — Returns canonicalized absolute pathname; dirname — Returns parent directory's path. It's all in the word parent

Answer (score 3):

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using explode(), array_pop() and implode() :

```
<?php

//$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = "/var/www/html/clients/app/folder";
$tmp = explode("/", $path);
array_pop($tmp);
$path_up = implode('/', $tmp);
echo $path_up; //output: /var/www/html/clients/app

?>
```